# SSH : Remotely run a script and stay there

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I wish to run a script on the remote system and then wish to stay there.
Running following script:-

```
ssh user@remote logs.sh
```

This do run the script but after that I am back to my host system. i need to stay on remote one. I tried with..

```
ssh user@remote logs.sh;bash -l
```

somehow it solves the problem but still not working exactly as a fresh login as the command:-

```
ssh user@remote
```

Or it will be better if i could include something in my script that would open the bash terminal in the same directory where the script was running. Please suggest.

Comment: Can't you just do `ssh user@remote logs.sh; ssh user@remote`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working exactly as a fresh login"?

Comment: it didnt work for me. indeed, the first command (logs) was ran correctly, but as soon as I pressed CTRL-C to get to the terminal it broke the SSH connection altogether

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh -t user@remote 'logs.sh; bash -l'
```

The quotes are needed to pass both commands to `ssh`.  The `-t` option forces a  pseudo-tty allocation.

#### Discussion

Consider:

```
ssh user@remote logs.sh;bash -l
```

When the shell parses this line, it splits it into two commands.  The first is:

```
ssh user@remote logs.sh
```

This runs `logs.sh` on the remote machine.  The second command is:

```
bash -l
```

This opens a login shell *on the local machine*.

The quotes were added above to prevent the shell from splitting up the commands this way.

Comment: Throw in a `-t` to allocate a `pty` because he's trying to get an interactive shell rather than just running a command; and if you pass commands to ssh, it doesn't allocate a tty by default

Comment: @Petesh Thanks.  `bash -i` worked but `ssh -t` works much better. Answer updated.

Comment: In addition -- To run a command after your `ssh` sessions finishes: `ssh -t user@remote 'logs.sh; bash -l';  echo "--[remote session done]--";`.  That message prints after you exit.  Or you can have whatever else you fancy.

Comment: what if the shell script is not on the remote machine, how can we run the shell script from local machine to the remote without uploading?