# Running a remote script

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I want to run script B on machine B by a call from script A on machine A that is run by crontab on regular interval. I'm not a unix user myself and after looking at similar questions, couple things are confusing to me.

1. Are single quotes necessary because I see they're sometimes used but sometimes not used.

   ```
   ssh user@host './path/foo.sh'
   ssh user@host foo.sh
   ```
2. If I want to use variables will this work:A.sh:

   ```
   path="some/path"
   ssh user@host @path/foo.sh
   ```

   or do I need to put them in single quotes?
3. Is password always needed? The answers at [how to run a script file remotely using ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041597/how-to-run-a-script-file-remotely-using-ssh) had no mention of passwords at all, so I was wondering if there are types of scripts that require password and those that don't. Since my script will have to run on schedule, I would need to automate the authentication process. I found several solutions that involve expect scripts, key-pair authentication. But [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360288/ssh-remotely-run-a-script-and-stay-there) that have no mention of passwords have me questioning whether if they're necessary at all.

Comment: These are two/three orthogonal questions. I would suggest moving the last one to a separate question (although you will definitely find answers here and on unix.stackexchange.com about passwordless ssh).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Single quotes are only necessary if the string contains special characters, most notably spaces. Almost anything inside single quotes is interpreted literally by the shell.
2. Variables are expanded using `$`, not `@`, but you cannot use it inside single quotes, so you are better off using double quotes for that. Those still protect against spaces, but allow for `$` expansion:

   ```
   path="some/path"
   ssh user@host "$path/foo.sh"
   ```
3. To `ssh` to a remote machine, you typically use either a password or a keypair. For automation, a keypair is pretty much your only option, because you don't want to store the password in plain text anywhere and `ssh` makes it difficult to input it from a file anyway.